# Trigger tab refresh on tab click in visual composer

Tags: wordpress, visual-composer

I have an iframe inside a visual composer (wpbakery) tab - can I trigger a refresh of this iframe/other wordpress shortcode when the tab is clicked?

Thanks lot!

Answer (score 0):

The fastest solution is to create a jQuery function for the click on the button.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
   console.log('test'); jQuery('#idTab').click(function(){
      console.log('test');
        $("#iframe").attr("src", function(index, attr){ 
        return attr;
    });
   });
});
```

You find a demo here https://codepen.io/dextlore/pen/JjKvaGM

Comment: thank you for your kidn reply. I am using visual composer (wpbakery) - added your code as raw javascript and changed the tab and iframe ids- now I cannot press the tab - what can eb wrong?